# Why is solr admin panel not showing?

Tags: jetty, solr

I have downloaded solr from [here](http://apache.cyberuse.com/lucene/solr/3.1.0/apache-solr-3.1.0-src.tgz) and untar'd it. Then went to the example directory in `apache-solr-3.1.0/solr/example` and ran this command

```
java -jar start.jar
```

But when I open `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/`

it shows like this

> HTTP ERROR: 404 Problem accessing /solr/admin/.
>
> Reason:
>
> NOT_FOUND
>
> Powered by Jetty://

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04. Why this problem is coming?

Answer (score 4):

1. Stop Solr
2. Go to the directory where you run "java -jar start.jar"
3. `mkdir work`
4. `java -jar start.jar`

It seems that Jetty will use the `work` directory if it exists, otherwise it uses `/tmp`

Answer (score 2):

I've been experiencing this issue as well and finally found the details and resolution to the matter.  The issue (as I understand) is specific to using Jetty as your servlet container.

The cause is that Jetty will place some files in the OS's `/tmp` directory--and occasionally the OS will delete them.  In this scenario your admin pages will start returning 404's with the exception you've mentioned, but all searches and queries continue to execute as normal.

The solution is simple: creating a `work` subdirectory underneath your `jetty.home` folder (a runtime variable) will solve the problem.  Jetty will see the `work` folder and will place temporary files in that location rather than in `/tmp`.  The OS doesn't manage this location and therefore won't delete files that are still in use.

There is a bug report detailing this issue and resolution filed at: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-118

Answer (score 0):

It is probably better to ask for help on a different forum, because the problem you have does not seem to have any connection with ubuntu.

Anyway, one of the first hits on google brings me to: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Adding-the-suggest-component-td2694982.html
Try running:

```
    ant clean example
```

prior to  `java -jar start.jar`

Answer (score 0):

If your install is running mostly with the defaults, then Jetty's work files are probably in /tmp where they may have been wiped.

Stop and restart Solr after creating a $(jetty.home)/work directory and you should stop seeing the 404s.

Comment: WHERE IS JETTY.HOME

Comment: @Rahul Mehta its in gem file sunspot_solr-2.1.0\solr\etc\jetty.xml

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problems and finally solved it with using version from here
http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/3.5.0/  but only when I downloaded zip version.
No Idea why.

Comment: Did you have the problem with 3.1.0 and found that 3.5.0 fixed it but 4.8.1 didn't?  And you tried the .tgz which didn't work and then the .zip did?  I strongly suspect you changed something else at the same time as trying the zip-encoded version 3.5.0 and that *something else* is the real reason it worked.